# Best practice to protect android library's source code?

Tags: android

I would like to build a library that is used for applications. The library is not free. I intend to code it by using C++, and compile into binary files which my clients can import to their Android applications (written by Java/Kotlin).

This is just my roughly idea, I haven't done any similar thing previously.

Could someone who used to do same thing before guide me the best practice for this kind of library?

Answer (score 2):

At the end of the day, if you give someone binaries, they will be able to reverse engineer it to some extent no matter what you do. With that said, there are a few things you can do to make reverse engineering really hard.

- First, you'll *only* want to provide C++ headers for your user (that don't expose implementation details). Then, you'll distribute the actual `.dll` or `.so` compiled binary, of which they can only access the assembly code. A great example of this strategy I've seen is [Porcupine](https://github.com/Picovoice/porcupine), who only distributes headers.
- You can look into code obfuscation, but this probably isn't worth it for C++. If you have Java parts to the library though, this could help.
- Set a restrictive license on your library, *most* well-intended developers would rather find an alternative library upon seeing your non-open source license rather than wasting time stealing it and reverse engineering it. Porcupine also has a licensing system (and the library will expire without a valid  license). So you could look into that as well.
- Does your library have to be local? Can some parts be hidden behind an API that your users could call instead?
- Only distribute your library to paying customers (do not provide headers, binaries, or anything to non-subscribers).